# How to use OR in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings like "abc", "def", "xyz" and they may be followed by numbers.
For example:
abc123 or xyz92

If I use:

```
re.findall("abc|def|xyz[0-9]+",text)
```

then it will only return xyz followed by digits, for the rest I only get the strings.

How to match all of them without doing it manually like:

```
re.findall("abc[0-9]+|def[0-9]+|xyz[0-9]+",text)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use parenthesis, along with `?:` to create a non-capturing group:

```
(?:abc|def|xyz)[0-9]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mC0ygke6rJC0XuYN)

Further, if it is possible that your strings will not be followed by numbers, you should use `*` (0 or more), instead of `+` (1 or more). This way `abc` and `abc123` will both match:

```
(?:abc|def|xyz)[0-9]*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LVg84ZMwgxKqxroX)

This is your current regex:

```
abc|def|xyz[0-9]+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/P_CI69oPJWcvm2my)

Comment: This is an excellent way to explain how the regular expressions work. Good job!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the visual explanation and also this debuggex is great!

Comment: AFAIK non capturing group doesn't capture characters inside parenthesis. so(?:abc|xyz|def)[0-9]+ should only return the numeric part right...but its instead returning the whole string.

Comment: That's not how non-capturing group works, @svetaketu. Non-capturing groups will match, just not capture (and be read with backreferences `\1`)